# Dependency Resolution with a config File

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Before Asp.Net.Core, when I hosted my WEBAPI code, I use Unity and Unity.configuration to define my DI.

Something like this:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <container>
        <register type="MyLibrary.Interfaces.IDepartmentManager, MyLibrary"
              mapTo="MyLibrary.DepartmentManager, MyLibrary" />
        <register type="MyLibrary.Interfaces.IFtpFileSender, MyLibrary"
              mapTo="MyLibrary.FtpFileSender, MyLibrary" />
    </container>
</unity>
```

Now I'm getting into AspNetCore.

I figured out how "coding it up" works.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            /* THE MAGIC !! */
            services.AddTransient<MyLibrary.Interfaces.IDepartmentManager, MyLibrary.DepartmentManager>();
            services.AddTransient<MyLibrary.Interfaces.IFtpFileSender, MyLibrary.FtpFileSender>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use a configuration file (MyDependencies.json) or something with the new/baked-in dependency engine?

This is the closest thing I've found

https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/08/16/diwithconfiguration/

But not a direct hit.

Comment: Perhaps some fundamentals will help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration

Comment: why would you want to do it with a json file? That case it won't be typed, so if you change a class, it will break at runtime (if you forget to change it)...

Comment: Why did unity support it?  Of course the text in the file needs to be correct.  One scenario is that you have multiple clients who need a different ISomething.  You want to compile the code but through installers pick a different ISomething.  There is also the ability to provide a default ISomething in config, but allow it to be overwritten with a yet to be written implementation.  Which is a mimic of things like the old aspnet provider model did.